# Tumblr AVATAR API grabbing

Tags: tumblr

i'm doing a website and i want my visitors to leave a comment but instead of showing the tipical gravatar, i want to display their tumblr avatar just by putting their URL.

See, i'm using wordpress, there's a plugin for that but it's for twitter only.

does anyone know what i need to change to make it work for tumblr?

The plug in is called Twitter Avatar reloaded

i tried to change the tumblr API but id didn't work or does anyone know another method?

i'm kind of desperate, i just want to grab the tumblr avatar like in this website [tumblrplug.com](http://tumblrplug.com)

Thanks i'd really appreciate any solution!

here you can see the plugin

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/twitter-avatar-reloaded/

Answer (score 0):

have you tried something along a call to :

```
http://api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/david.tumblr.com/avatar
```

check this documentation for more information - http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/api/v2#blog-avatar

Comment: yes i've tried it but i'm not sure how to use it on wordpress.